# Show that a complex equation represents a circle

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers, circles, conic-sections

I'm having troubling understanding the answer to a question. The question is:

If $\ v=1+i$ and $\ z=x+iy$, for any real numbers x and y:
Show that the equation   $\left|z-v\right|= \left|vz\right|$ represents a circle, and find its centre and radius.

The answers states:

$\ vz = (1+i)(x+iy) = (x-y) +i(x+y)$
so $\left|z-v\right|= \left|vz\right|$
becomes $\ (x-1)^2 + (y-1)^2 = (x-y)^2 + (x+y)^2$
$\ -2x - 2y +2 = x^2 + y^2 $
...

The part I don't understand is how they remove $\ i $.

Comment: It's the definition of absolute value of a complex number: If $z=x+iy$ then $|z|=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$

Comment: You found the product $vz$ correctly, so, $|vz|=\sqrt{(x-y)^{2}+(x+y)^{2}}$. You now need to find $z-v$ and then $|z-v|$. Then, simplify $|z-v|=|vz|$ to get the equation of the circle (you may need to use completing the square method). Simply put, the equation of the circle will be $|vz|^{2}-|z-v|^{2}=0$ which you need to rewrite in the form $(x-a)^{2}+(y-b)^{2}=r^{2}$.

Comment: @Nami, in fact you are nearly there. The last equation you got $-2x-2y+2=x^{2}+y^{2}$ is the equation of the circle. Use completing the square method to rewrite it in the form $(x-a)^{2}+(y-b)^{2}=r^{2}.$